# Splitting data into 2 column in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, select, sql-insert

I have 1 columns in table `ColA`, `ColB` in which I want to store some values. There is another table from which I am selecting the information and will insert into this table. `ColA` has `VARCHAR(25)` length and `ColB` also has `VARCHAR(25)` length. Now the data I an fetching is more than the allocated length. Let's say it has 35 characters, how can I split and choose 25 character in `ColA` and rest in `ColB` ? Is it really a bad practice or bad way to ask such question ?

```
INSERT INTO Master_Table
SELECT Val AS ColA, NULL AS ColB FROM Child_Table
```

Hope I have explained what I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you need the Oracle database built-in function named [SUBSTR](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/character-functions/oracle-substr-function.php) ?

Comment: Show us some sample child_table data, and what you want to be inserted into master_table. (Use formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions:

```
INSERT INTO Master_Table(ColA, ColB)
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(Val, 1, 25),    -- the first 25 characters of the string
    SUBSTR(Val, 26)        -- the reminder (if any)
FROM Child_Table
```

The three-argument form of `SUBSTR()` lets you define the starting point and the number of characters to take. The two-arguments form takes everything from the given position until the end of the string. If the starting point is greater than the length of the string, this returns a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice, most probably.

Use `SUBSTR`, e.g.

```
insert into master_table (cola, colb)
  select substr(input_value, 1, 25),    --> first 25 characters go to COLA
         substr(input_value, 26)        --> the rest goes to COLB
  from another_table;
```